# Splash Page For Users Who Did Not Authorize App Yet

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

We have a facebook game that uses the Facebook C# SDK 5.2.1.0. We would like a splash page for users who have not yet authorized. My code is set up basically like this: https://gist.github.com/879932.

I'm guessing I need a way to know if the user is authorized BEFORE I send them off to get authorized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript SDK and call FB.getLoginStatus() and let the clientside do the redirection for you.  :)